# Does Storybook now load Angular styles.scss automatically?

Tags: angular, sass, storybook, angular-storybook

In previous versions of Storybook if we wanted the stories to render with the Angular SASS in `styles.scss` included we had to add this import to `preview.ts`:

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!../src/styles.scss';
```

And I noticed that in the current version (7.5.3) this is no longer necessary.  Does Storybook Angular do this automatically now?